# Using a hash map in a Format-Table expression

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the following example from [Use Windows PowerShell to Manage Virtual Machines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722740.aspx) article on TechNet to work:

```
$VMState = @{
    2="Running"
    3="Stopped"
    32768="Paused"
    32769="Suspended"
    32270="Starting"
    32771="Snapshotting"
    32773="Saving"
    32774="Stopping"
}

$vms = get-wmiobject -computername localhost -Namespace root\Virtualization -query "Select * from MSVM_Computersystem where Description like '%Virtual%' "
$vms | format-table -autosize @{Label=”VM Name”; expression = {$_.elementName}}, Description, @{Label =”VM State”; expression = {$VmState[$_.EnabledState]}}
```

For some reason, I don't get the enabled state mapped correctly, and get nothing, like so:

```
VM Name Description               VM State
------- -----------               --------
SANS    Microsoft Virtual Machine         
SERIF   Microsoft Virtual Machine
```

Why doesn't this part work?

```
expression = {$VmState[$_.EnabledState]}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the $vms.EnabledState are set to values that match your hashmap?

Comment: Yes, SANS is 2, and SERIF is 3 (I checked by printing the contents of $vms).

Also, I tried using EnavledState instead of using a label-expression key-value pair, similar to how they use Description. The right numbers were printed in the 3rd column.

Comment: Could it be that $VMStates variable is not accessible from within the expression? I don't know how to check. I guess I could print something. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your hashtable to the below and try:

```
$VMState = @{
    "2"="Running"
    "3"="Stopped"
    "32768"="Paused"
    "32769"="Suspended"
    "32270"="Starting"
    "32771"="Snapshotting"
    "32773"="Saving"
    "32774"="Stopping"
}
```

Alternative would be to make sure that the `$_.EnabledState` is int - `[int]$_.EnabledState`

Note that

```
$a="2"
$VMState[$a] #gives nothing
$a=2
$VMState[$a] #gives Running
```

Comment: I've run into type problems using WMI properties as keys for hashtables before.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I preferred the 2nd alternative.